# localization in pivot turn

Tags: robot-localization, ros-noetic, ekf, navsat-transform-node

I have a question about position estimation when a robot performs pivot turn.
In pivot turn, it is ideal for only the robot's yaw angle to change, while the x and y positions remain constant.
But, I have found that during actual pivot turn of the robot, the the estimated x and y values from EKF change by about 1 meter.
(the estimated x and y values from wheel odometry remain unchanged)
After completing the pivot turn, the estimated x and y values from EKF converge to their initial values.

To Reproduce Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Set up the robot according to the instructions on the following website
   https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html
2. launch robot_localization and pivot the robot on the spot.

Expected behavior

- the estimation results for x and y remain unchanged with the EKF, while only the yaw angle of the robot changes.

Desktop (please complete the following information):

- OS : ubuntu20.04
- ROS Distribution : noetic
- robot_localization Package Version : latest (using ekf and navsat)
- GNSS Device ZED-F9P (output rate 5Hz)

Comment: It is not clear what inputs does your EKF use. Do you use GPS in the fusion? Also, what motion model does your robot follow? Is it diff drive? And are you sure pivot turns of your robot actually turn around the geometrical center of your robot? When one side of the robot is heavier, it tends to pull the center of rotation from the geometrical axis towards the heavier side.

Comment: Please include your full EKF config (remove all comments) and a sample message from every sensor input.